# Can we process a form with Symfony2 without redirect to another url at the end?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I have problem with processing the data on a form in two tables with Ajax for not updating screen. Sumfony2 redirects to process the data to a url in the end, as you can see in the following code:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
 {
    $entity = new Users();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

       if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();


    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_new'));
     }

    return $this->render('BackendBundle:Userss:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

ajax call:

```
$('.form_student').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: Routing.generate('student_create'),
data: $(this).serialize(),

success: function(response) {

 alert(response.result);

  },
 error: function (xhr, desc, err){

 alert("error");
}
})
return false;
});
```

Is there any way that does not forward it to any URL and can use Ajax to load anything in that window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check on the $request if is an ajax call with the `isXmlHttpRequest` method.

So you can do something like:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
....
if ($form->isValid()) {

    // do something
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            // generate a response for tour client, as example:
            return new JsonResponse(array("result" => 1);
        }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_new'));
 }
```

Hope this help

Comment: I still can not use the value of the response in ajax, I used your example `alert (data.result);` to check the return value, but it indicates that it is undefined. How is the response object used in Ajax? Could you also tell me how I can spend errors validated fields in symfony form to return the response to I can show errors without refreshing the page?

Comment: Hi @Joseph is difficult to respond with a standard response... i usually do this stuff via a custom approach in combination with a custom js ajax management....

Comment: Hi @Matteo, excuse me but I have not understood, I guess you refer to the second thing I ask right ?. I add the above code ajax call to see an attempt to use the Paraque answer me indicate whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Hi @Joseph i respond to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066421/form-validation-in-symfony-from-ajax-call/34069322#34069322

Comment: I just saw now, I think I will do a great help for what I've seen, but I'm still doing something wrong because I can not get in ajax the value of the controller response. I'm testing with an alert (response.result); and tells me that it is undefined, you know where I could be wrong?

Comment: Hi @Joseph now i understand, you need to respond with the a json rensponse in a succesfully scenario also. Probably you are on the case of a valid response? In this case the response in the ajax is the value of the html page of the redirect

Comment: No @Matteo, I changed it when you told me the other answer, so it should return the JsonResponse

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('users_new'));
```

by

```
return new JsonResponse($this->generateUrl('users_new'));
```

this will return the url instead of redirecting to it, you can then use javascript to load it.

Comment: First thanks for the reply @AmineMatmati. Forgive me for the ignorance but I don't know how to use that response in javascript. My idea would be that once the form data are stored in the database, it load the url that redirects the controller for example with jquery load function