# Symfony 2 Getting form errors with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

```
$errors = array();

if ($form instanceof Form) {

    foreach ($form->getErrors(true, true) as $error) {
         $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I'm using AJAX request with my registration form. The JSON response now is like:
`["error1", "error2", "error3"]`
. Code above works for me but I would like to get fields names aswell. I've tried few solutions but any of them works for me.

Comment: have you already see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066421/form-validation-in-symfony-from-ajax-call/34069322#34069322

Comment: Thanks, that works for me perfectly.

Comment: hi @nix9 you are welcome! happy to know that help someone!